# StackNavigator inside TabNavigator can't change nav bar color

Tags: react-native

I have a StackNavigator:

```
const infoNavigator = StackNavigator({
InfoMain: {
    screen: PFInfoMain,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Information',
        tintColor: 'red'
    }
},
InfoDetail: {screen: PFInfoDetail}
});
```

inside of a TabNavigator:

iOS:

```
const iosTabs = TabNavigator({
Info: {
    screen: infoNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Info',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/home.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        )
    }
}...
```

Android:

```
const androidTabs = TabNavigator(
{
    Info: {screen: infoNavigator} ...
```

The navigationOptions with the tintColor: 'red' in infoNavigator is just one of myriad failed attempts to set the color of the nav bar (header?).

Nothing has worked.

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `react-navigation`,

There is no such thing as `tintColor` mentioned in their [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html).

User [`headerTintColor`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#headertintcolor) or [`headerStyle`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#headerstyle)

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
       headerTintColor: "red",
       headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor:"red"
       }
   });
```

Comment: headerTintColor changes the text color in the nav bar.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!  I swear I've tried that before and got an error about objects not being allowed there or something.  Thanks again